# How do I disable Drupal 7 Theme Debug? "drush vset theme_debug 0" NOT WORKING

Tags: 7

I enabled theme debug on my drupal 7 installation using `drush vset theme_debug 1`, But Now I can't disable theme debug using `drush vset theme_debug 0`, What the wrong, Is there any wrong or mistakes in the drush command above?

I also tried to comment out `$conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;` in the settings.php and then replaced with `$conf['theme_debug'] = FALSE;` but none works.

Any help and suggestions on this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have file local.setting.php?

Comment: Hi @Jonh, Thanks for quick replying. I don't have local.setting.php. I can see there is a file called default.setting.php & setting.php in sites/default directory.

Comment: try to execute `drush vset theme_debug 0` with `--debug`  to see if there is any errors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using `drush vset theme_debug 0` doesn't work. Try disabling the theme debugging on your `settings.php` file, adding the below line of code:

```
$conf['theme_debug'] = FALSE;
```

Don't forget clear the cache.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I actually did that but NO LUCK. You can check my question description where I mentioned this. However, I may messed up everything, getting a lot of error log message.

Comment: Hay @heilop, After restoring a backup, `drush vset theme_debug 0` started working again. Thanks for your answer. You suggestion also working now.

Comment: @AbuZafor, You're welcome!